# Como apagar input e trazer de volta as opções do filtro

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html5

Boa tarde tenho um cod. de filtro que funciona muito bem, ele esta dentro de um dialog, só que preciso que quando eu sair do dialog que esta no mesmo html, o valor do input retorne a vazio e as opções que sumiram conforme foi digitado apareça de novo. so pra simplificar eu fiz um botao reset, que apaga meu input mais nao traz as opçoes de volta, so traz de volta se eu apagar manualmente.

esse e meu cod.

```
<img class="opener4" src="./imagem/gravata.png"   style="width: 25px;  margin-left: 10px; cursor:pointer; "/>
<h4 class="opener4"  id="titulo2">Gerenciando</h4>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade ola" id="ModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div  class="modal-content quartoModal">
            <div class="modal-header modais">
                <h2  class="modal-title"  id="ModalLongTitle">Gerenciando</h2>
                <br></br>
                <img class="voltar" src="./imagem/voltar.png"  style="cursor:pointer;"  />
                <form >
                    <input type="reset"  value="Reset"/>
                    <input id="txtBusca" class="txtBusca" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus"  type="text" placeholder="&ensp;&ensp;Procurar &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;"/>
                </form>
                <h3 style="margin-left: 100px">Business Intelligence</h3>
                <ul class="ulItens">
                    <li> <a href="#"    type="button" id="btn-btn" class=" voltar"><img  alt="" id="logo" src="./imagem/dashboard.png" />&ensp;&ensp;Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"    type="button" id="btn-btn" class=" voltar"><img  alt="" id="logo" src="./imagem/producer.png" />&ensp;&ensp;Produtores</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"    type="button" id="btn-btn" class=" voltar"><img  alt="" id="logo" src="./imagem/producao.png"/>&ensp;&ensp;Produção Agrícola</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"    type="button" id="btn-btn" class=" voltar"><img  alt="" id="logo" src="./imagem/arrecadacao.png" />&ensp;&ensp;Arrecadação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

//esse para abrir o dialog

```
$(function() {
    $( ".quintoModal" ).dialog({
        width: 450,
        autoOpen: false,
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top+50"},
        show: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 1200,
          easing:"easeOutExpo",
          direction:"left", 
          distance:800, 
        },
        hide: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 1000,
          easing:"easeInExpo",
          direction:"left", 
          distance:800, 
        },
    });
    $( ".opener5" ).click(function() {
        $( ".quintoModal" ).dialog( "open");
        $( ".quintoModal" ).dialog( "option", "resizable", false );
        $( ".quintoModal" ).dialog( "option", "draggable", false );

        $(".voltar").click(function () {
          $( ".quintoModal" ).dialog( "close" );
        });
    });
});
```

// esse  e o filtro

```
$(function(){
    $(".txtBusca").on("keyup", function(){
        var texto = $(this).val();
        $(".ulItens li").css("display", "block");
        $(".ulItens li").each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto.toUpperCase()) < 0)
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
       close: function (event, ui) {
            $('#idInput').val("");
       }
   });
```

Comment: Diogo descreva melhor a sua resposta, apenas o código solto assim não ajuda as pessoas que por ventura tenha o mesmo problema. Tente ser mais claro.

Answer (score 1):

É um modal bootstrap?

Se for, é só você fazer o seguinte

```
$('#ModalLong').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#txtBusca').val('');
})
```

O evento `hidden.bs.modal` é disparado toda vez que o modal é fechado. Ali você pode programar algum tipo de comportamento.